# Unable to import mysql.connector in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

I have installed mysql-connector package as follows:

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

When I run `pip show mysql-connector`, i get the following output:

```
Name: mysql-connector
Version: 2.2.9
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
Home-page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html
Author: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Author-email: 
License: GNU GPLv2 (with FOSS License Exception)
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Also, when i run sys.path, I get the following result:

```
/Users/<userhome>/pythondev/Files/home/mysql-python-dev
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

Yet, I am getting the following error in my vscode editor while trying to import the package:

```
Import "mysql.connector" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

Based on some of the previous answers to similar problems, it appears that this could be a vscode interpreter issue as vscode is prompting me to use a different interpreter.
Is there a simple way to resolve this issue? Do I need to change to a new interpreter? I am new to vscode and i don't know much about how to create a new interpreter and the impact it will have on the other libraries I use.

I've tried to resolve this for some time but I am stuck.

Comment: The output from `pip show` says that the module is installed for Python 3.8 in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8`, but your sys.path output says you are using Python 3.11 in `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11`.

Comment: You have two (or more) separate installations of python on your computer.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Thank you John for your help. Your observation was bang on. vscode is using the latest version of python whereas I had an older version on my mac that was installed previously. Pointing to the older interpreter resolved my issue. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This problem was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter.

You could use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter which you installed the python package in.